# Change color of words in a string that's been returned from a search query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of specific words in a string thats been returned from a search query. I have passed down a collection and its search terms from the server via SignalR and ideally looking to replace the words with some HTML. Any Pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
var searchReturnHTML = "";
            //tickets is the collection returned
            $.each(tickets, function ()
            {
                var tickets = this;

               //Search terms used in the query
                var data = tickets.SearchTerms;

               //Split the search terms
                var arr = data.toString().split(',');

                //Property in the collection
                var description = tickets.description;

                //Loop through the search term collection
                $.each(arr, function (k,v)
                {
                    //Apply color change, if a search term is matched in the return property string
                    var re = new RegExp(v, "g");
                    description = description.replace(re, "<span style='color:red;'>" + v + "</span>");
                });

                //Return HTML
                searchReturnHTML += "<div class='search-return-item'>" +
                                        "<p>#" + tickets.ticketID + "</p>" +
                                        "<p>" + description + "</p>" +
                                        "<p>" + "From: " + tickets.name + "</p>" +
                                        "<p><strong>" + tickets.SearchTerms + "</strong></p>" + 
                                   "</div>"



            });
```

At the minute the description returns as NaN. I'm not entirely sure why. Any Ideas? This works ok without the string manipulation.

Regards,

Tez

Comment: Why a down vote? Genuine question.

Comment: I think we'd need to know more about `tickets`. Also, did you check `console.log(description);` ?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about tickets..Other than it works and is constructed in the backend C# and passed down through SignalR. tickets is a collection with description as a property. In all honesty i have better understand on the backend rather than client side. So its quite rude that i get down voted. Anyhow thank you, i shall look into console.log.

Comment: No need to get huffy. I didn't downvote. Just trying to help. I don't understand what `tickets` is, and the error seems to indicate a problem with `description`, which comes from `tickets`.

Comment: Apologies, Just found it rude from the "down voters"...When running the VS debugger description is certainly being passed in. The problem is client side...Maybe jQuery version issue.

Comment: Try providing us with a test object we can construct of `tickets` so we can test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear slightly embarrassed! I actually wrote the question by hand and then went back to my code in VS and realised I missed something fundamental to get it to work.

Basically I did not have reference to the "description" variable

```
searchReturnHTML += "<div class='search-return-item'>" +
                                        "<p>#" + tickets.ticketID + "</p>" +
                                        "<p>" + **description** + "</p>" +
                                        "<p>" + "From: " + tickets.name + "</p>" +
                                        "<p><strong>" + tickets.SearchTerms + "</strong></p>" + 
                                   "</div>"
```

Apologies for wasting your time! Complete rookie mistake.

Regards,